# TreeView Control similar to that of utorrent

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, treeview

In uTorrent 2.2 when a treeview node is selected, the node has a similar appearance of a button. It makes the .NET treeview control seem like so inadequate to me.  Now I know utorrent is written in C++, but does anyone know how they might have done this, or does anybody know of libraries out there that would suffice?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a standard Windows TreeView control with the Win7 "Explorer" visual style applied.  You can get one in your own program easily by changing the theme for the control.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MyTreeView : TreeView {
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) {
            SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "Explorer", null);
        }
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }
    [DllImportAttribute("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string appname, string idlist);
}
```

This isn't directly possible for WPF unless you use the WindowsFormHost class.